# How to add pagination or filtering in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pagination, filtering, server-side-rendering

I'm looking for a solution to implement pagination or filtering in my web application using the traditional page routing method. Do I need to use Client Side data fetching? When query strings change it won't cause a re-render of the page content. I don't want to fetch my entire data with SSG and apply pagination on the client side. Can you provide suggestions or examples on how to achieve this effectively? Existing resources on this topic are limited, and I'm seeking guidance to handle dynamic data changes without compromising performance.

Tried to pass query strings to getServerSideProps but it only fetches data upon refresh. The page should show filtered/paginated content instantly on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. For those who are wondering, I actually made a mistake. I set the `shallow: true` inside of `router.push`. So my page was't re-rendering when I changed the query strings. When you are changing the query string, make sure to put `shallow: false` inside of `router.push`. Here is a example:

```
router.push({ 
    pathname: router.pathname, 
    query: { ...router.query } }, 
    undefined, 
    { 
       shallow: false
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial provided by Next.js https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination. There you can find an example of how to implement pagination and search.